# How can I print the longest word from a user defined list?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I have this code to print the longest word in a user defined list but i get null as the result. I have converted the list to a string but it still does not work.

```
public class no7 {

  public static String getLongestString(String[] array) {
      int maxLength = 0;
      String longestString =null;
      for (String s : array) {
          if (s.length() > maxLength) {
              maxLength = s.length();
              longestString = s;
          }
      }
      return longestString;
  }

  public static void main(String[] str) {


      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a list:");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     str = list.toArray(new String[0]);


     while (!in.hasNext("done") && !in.hasNext("Done") )
        {
        list.add(in.next());
        }

     String longestString = getLongestString(str);
      System.out.format("longest string: '%s'\n", longestString);



        }
  }
```

Comment: `public static void main(String[] str) {` and then `str = list.toArray(new String[0]);` that's not what `main`'s parameter is for, FYI.

Comment: Also, `str` will not contain what the user inputs if you assign to `str` the content of the list *before* filling the list itself.

Comment: Finally, why can't `getLongestString` simply accept and work with a `List` instead of an array? You're accessing it sequentially anyway.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do and even with given code only this needs to be changed `String longestString = getLongestString(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));` further more as many have pointed out why are you using `str` it has no user input

Comment: A more elegant ending condition for your while loop is "(?i)done". The (?i) at the beginning of a regex makes it case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `public static void main(String[] str) {` and then `str = list.toArray(new String[0]);` that's not what `main`'s parameter is for, FYI.

Also, `str` will not contain what the user inputs if you assign to `str` the content of the list *before* filling the list itself.

Finally, why can't `getLongestString` simply accept and work with a `List` instead of an array? You're accessing it sequentially anyway.

All of this translates to

```
public class no7 {

    public static String getLongestString(List<String> array) {
        int maxLength = 0;
        String longestString =null;
        for (String s : array) {
            if (s.length() > maxLength) {
                maxLength = s.length();
                longestString = s;
            }
        }
        return longestString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] str) {


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a list:");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();    

        while (!in.hasNext("done") && !in.hasNext("Done") )
        {
            list.add(in.next());
        }

        String longestString = getLongestString(list);
        System.out.format("longest string: '%s'\n", longestString);



    }
}
```

As a side note, `no7` for a class name does not respect the java naming convention. It should be `No7` (remember to rename the file accordingly).

Comment: thank you. How can I print two words of the same length and use comma as the separator?

Answer (score 2):

The answers provided by Federico klez Culloca and sleepToken are valid, I just want to clear your code a bit more, paying attention to the following:

- Use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to open and automatically close your Scanner.
- Prefer [referencing objects by their interfaces](http://jtechies.blogspot.com/2012/07/item-52-refer-to-objects-by-their.html). Even if you create an instance of `ArrayList<String>` it's preferable to assign the result to `List<String>`.
- Your code fails at detecting the end of input stream. You check for presence of the word 'done' or 'Done', but don't check if any word is available at all. If the stream is closed without sending 'done' or 'Done' then your program stops with an exception.
- You can get the string with a maximum length using a one-liner with Java stream API.

```
  public static String getLongestString(List<String> strings) {
    return strings.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).orElse(null);
  }

  public static void main(String[] str) {
    System.out.println("Enter a list:");
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      while (in.hasNext()) {
        String next = in.next();
        if ("done".equalsIgnoreCase(next)) {
          break;
        }
        list.add(next);
      }
      String longestString = getLongestString(list);
      System.out.format("longest string: '%s'%n", longestString);
    }
  }
```

Comment: + for "try with resources" .  It's still not C++'s destructors, but it's considerably better than nothing.  I'm undecided on `List<> foo = ArrayList<>`

Answer (score 1):

Forget messing with `main` args - and there's also no need to track the maxLength. String.length() already does that for you.

Don't forget to close your scanner. :~p

**Edit:** If you want to print the ties, you can store each word in a `HashMap` mapping lenghts -> words.

For example:

```
3 -> "cat", "dog"
4 -> "door", "tree", "frog"
```

Now we can find the largest key (4) and return the list of those words.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a list:");

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(!in.hasNext("done") && !in.hasNext("Done")) {
            list.add(in.next());
        }

        String longestString = getLongestString(list);
        System.out.format("longest string: '%s'\n", longestString);

        in.close();
    }

     public static String getLongestString(ArrayList<String> array) {
         Map<Integer, List<String>> lengths = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

          // Put each word in the HashMap, mapped by its length
          for (String s : array) {
              if (lengths.get(s.length()) == null) {
                  lengths.put(s.length(), new ArrayList<String>());
                  lengths.get(s.length()).add(s);
              } else {
                  lengths.get(s.length()).add(s);
              }
          }

          // Store the entry with the longest length
          Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> maxEntry = null;

          for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : lengths.entrySet()) {
              if (maxEntry == null || entry.getKey() > maxEntry.getKey()) {
                  maxEntry = entry;
              }
          }

          return maxEntry.getValue().toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "");
      }
}
```

Comment: thank you, what if I want to print two words of the same length separated by a comma?

Comment: Is it possible to do it without hashmap?

Comment: @SuwasnaPAKHRIN Well, if you *did* track `maxLength`, you could iterate through every item in the list again and concatinate every string with `.length() == maxLength`, and add commas.